# Append to geosjon file and save as .js file

Tags: javascript, python, geojson

I want to append `"var data ="` to geojson file and save it as `.js`  but the file is created with "var data = None;
I´m new to Python and I´ve read about the error, but don't know how to solve the issue. I manage to create geojson file from csv.
Thanks for the help.

```py
collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open("geoData.geojson", "w") as f:
    
    geojson_str = json.dump(collection, f, indent=4)
    output_filename = 'geometry.js'
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('var data = {};'.format(geojson_str))
```

Comment: Remove first `json.dump()` call, you're consuming file without saving result.

Comment: Hi Olvin. I did thanks. It does create fist file properly, and second file, but it comes empty. "var data = None;"

Comment: `json.dump()` returns `None`.

Comment: @Olvin, thanks. I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that worked and managed to create the two files I needed was:

```
collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open("geoData3.geojson", "w") as f:

    json.dump(collection, f, indent=4)

    output_filename = 'geometry.js'
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('var data = {};'.format(collection))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).